# IsolatedStorage ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

I don't see what's the matter here:

Constructor:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf;
        public FileManagement()
        {
            isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        }
```

when I save files:

```
   public bool saveCredentials(String username, String userpass)
        {
            bool res = false;

            StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("usercred.custom",
                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, isf));
            writeFile.WriteLine(username);
            writeFile.WriteLine(userpass);
            res = true;

            return res;
        }
```

and when I try to read them:

```
public String readUsername()
    {
        String username = "";
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isf.OpenFile("usercred.custom", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
        username = reader.ReadLine();

        return username;
    }
```

Reading returns null.

I try to save a file and write something into it, but it somehow doesn't work.

Comment: Protip: if you tell us how it doesn't work, we'll tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Please ensure all your streams are closed using .Close(), and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close your streams. Please add reader.Close(), writefile.Close() and fileStream.Close() before return and try again.